# Any way to move items in Sharepoint 2013 where everything can keep as much as original?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, move

After moving items with file explorer we found that some versioning information are modified or lost.

When using export/import library, the “last modified by” is changed.

Therefore, we would like to know how to move/copy any items (documents, library, list, file, document set, subsites, etc) within or cross site collections where everything (like permissions, version history, content types, last modified by, last modified date, etc) can keep as original.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the migration tools

- Metalogix
- Tzunami
- AvePoint

[Some more vendors](http://www.cmswire.com/cms/information-management/sharepoint-migration-14-vendors-that-can-make-it-happen-022261.php)

All the metadata is retained from source after migration

Comment: So, there is no build-in functions for that?

Comment: Is the following work for SharePoint 2013?
http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/

Comment: For moving content within a site collection you can use Content and Structure from Site Settings.

Comment: The tool seems pretty good and also the guy who created that is a SharePoint expert so all should fine.However as mentioned in the post you will need to run within a SharePoint server.If you have access to your server you can look into it